# Get a file from a git repository at a specific revision number

Tags: git, svn

I have a Git repository in which there files are committed through only one branch. I just use these commands:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "msg"
```

I want to get a specific revision of the file. This revision is specified with a number. Currently I use this:

if total number of revisions is 1: `git show HEAD:path`

and if the revision number is > 1, then: `git show HEAD~n:path`

However, when I run the code there are some cases in which I get an error saying something like: Invalid object name: HEADn (where n is a number). In subversion I used the `svn cat` command.

#### Update

Since I update the repository constantly, I don't want to checkout the repository at a revision if possible.

Comment: Git uses hashes, not numbers for revisions.

Comment: Is it possible to get the hash from a number? How can I get those numbers? There should be some way.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the `nth` submitted document.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your workflow, if you need to constantly check out specific old versions of a file. Git is designed to track the whole project, so this isn't a very natural thing to do with git. For example, store the file with a running number: 1-file, 2-file, ...

Comment: @KallePokki But then I wouldn't be able to store files efficiently.

Comment: It doesn't affect the size of your repository. Only the size if your checkout is different, and you already seem to have several different versions of the file checked out.

Comment: No checkout, just a temporary retrieval. As I mentioned before, I'm not looking for a checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other commands equivalent to `svn cat`:

```
git cat-file blob ref:path/to/file
git show ref:path/to/some/file.cs.
```

See [Specifying Revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) for replacing ref by (a SHA1, a tag, a branch, ... or, as you are using, `<rev>~<n>, e.g. master~3`)

Comment: Seems like this is what I wanted. (The link you posted)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to remember about git, is that everything is based around your commits. A commit hash identifies it, and tags, branches are just additional mechanisms to identify a commit, though in the case of a branch its not static, it moves with the HEAD.

so..in order to checkout the file at a particular revision, you just need to find what commit that revision was in, you can look at the history of a particular file with this...

```
git log --no-merges --oneline -- <path>
```

or if you are using Git Extensions or other GUI there will be a file history command to show you visually.

Once you know what the commit hash is you can checkout the file at that point using

```
git checkout <hash>:<path>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this with a program, not manually. Can the log be easily parsed with with a program? Is this method efficient enough?

Comment: Sure, everything I just posted can be scripted and parsed.